# Python pivot_table over large files with 4000 unique categories

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a data frame

```
  ClientId  Scrips   Scrips_viewed
0    A123    Ibank           5
1    B234    SteelCorp      10
2    B234    KTTelecom       8
3    A123    JKFlights       5
4    A123    BPharma         3
```

I am trying to do pivot_tables with all the unique scrips in columns and all client ids in index column and views in their respective column.

data.shape is 741206 rows × 3 columns

```
df_matrix = pd.pivot_table(data, values='Scrips_viewed', index='ClientId', columns='Scrips')
```

But my PC is getting hanged and I have to restart it again.

My unique Scrips count is 4200 ie. 4200 columns and my unique clients is 85,000.
My Ram is 16 GB

My error is

```
else:
   1231         # Note that no copy of zero-sized arrays is made. However since they

MemoryError:
```

Memory_usage(deep=True)

```
Index                   80
ClientId         11354188
Scrips             1921078
Scrips_viewed     5929648
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably reduce the memory your dataframe takes by converting the string columns to [categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

```py
data[["ClientId", "Scrips"]] = data[["ClientId", "Scrips"]].astype('category')
```

And then try to pivot.

Comment: Tried this, entire PC hanged and then memory error.

Comment: Can you check the output of data.memory_usage(deep=True) after converting to categorical and post it here?